# How are strings serialized in Tezos?

Tags: pack, serialization, string, bytes

How are strings serialized to byte arrays? I understand that they are treated like strings, and that ASCII (or utf8) encoding is used. But what about the rest of the bytes, what do they mean?

Running the LIGO CLI, I got:

```
$ ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack(("Hello World!"))'
0x05010000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c6421
```

where the latter part, `48656c6c6f20576f726c6421` is simply the hexadecimal representation of the ASCII values of the string. But is the type and the length of the string also encoded somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are serialized as follows:

1. `01` to indicate type string
2. Four bytes (eight hex chars) to indicate length of string: `0000000c`=`0x0c`=`12` in your case
3. The string represented by its ASCII values: `48656c6c6f20576f726c6421` in your case

The `05` in the beginning is a prefix which is only used by the `PACK` Michelson instruction which the `Bytes.pack` function in LIGO compiles down to.

Comment: The documentation for this can be found by running
`tezos-codec describe alpha.script.expr binary schema`
For output at the time of reading, see:
https://gist.github.com/smondet/f5b785a6bbe6adb431fd7bca5e6df91a